# Drupal 7 Views Filters - Change URL get Parameter 'Items_Per_Page' to just 'Items'

Tags: drupal, get, drupal-views, url-parameters, query-string

I have built an ecommerce website with Drupal 7 and use views and views filters for my product catalogue.

I would like to reduce the size of URL parameters for views filters to keep my URL's nice and short.

'**Items_Per_Page**' has no way of being changed in the UI.

I would like this to be changed to just '**Items**'.

Can this be achieved?

Example

My product catalogue has 5 filters; Category, Mod, Brand, System, and Items Per Page.

The current URL is: catalogue/?category=All&mod=All&brand=All&system=All&**items_per_page**=All

I would like to change this to:

catalogue/?category=All&mod=All&brand=All&system=All&**items**=All

Answer (score 0):

Please try the Better Exposed Filters module (https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters). You can setup your custom filter identifiers in the view settings with this module in order to achieve want you want.

Comment: Hello. Better Exposed Filters doesn't allow changing the identifier for Items_Per_Page. The options for Items_Per_Page are located with the pager options on the view edit page.